# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error). I already enabled my google sign in firebase. How can i fix

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use google sign in from firebase in my ionic angular project, I follow the tutorial, the compilation was good but when i click the sign in button it gives an error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
        
        
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
        
    authUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
        
    constructor(
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
    ) { }
        
    loginWithGoogle(): Observable<any>{
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        this.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then((response: auth.UserCredential) => {
        if (response.user) {
            this.authUser.next(response.user);
            observer.next({});
            observer.complete();
        }
        });
    });
    }
        
    logout() {
    this.auth.signOut().then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
    });
    }
        
    getLoggedInUser() {
    return this.authUser.asObservable();
    }
}
```

the error in the console says, ERROR

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).

[image: the error]

Comment: I have a similar error and does not lead to any answers. Did you find any solution?